# input lines from file into char array

Tags: c++

i am trying to read each line in the file B-small-practice.in into a char array but i am getting segmentation fault.

5

this is a test

foobar

all your base

class

pony along

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    ifstream a("B-small-practice.in",ios::in);

    int b,i=0;

    a>>b;

    char c[b][128];

    while(a.getline(c[i],128))
    {
        cout<<c[i];
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: can u please use char array instead of string in ur code

Comment: You're using a (probably g++) extension of C++ that allows variable-length arrays. In plain C++, arrays must have sized defined at compile-time: `int b,i=0; a>>b; char c[b][128];`

Comment: C++ does not support variable-length arrays (VLAs). You would be better off using a `std::vector<std::string>`. As written, your code won't even compile unless it is using a non-standard extension (such as the C++ VLAs from gnu).

Comment: The actual problem might come from a `\n` at the end of your file. Note your code in unsafe, see Captain Obvlious' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not doing any bounds checking the likely cause is you storing data past the end of the array. You can check the bounds in the `while` loop with something like the following...

```
while(i < b && a.getline(c[i],128))
{
    cout<<c[i];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't getline stop input if it encounters EOF

Comment: Yes but there is no guarantee that the file contains only `b` number of lines. If you read more than `b` number of lines you introduce undefined behavior as you are now storing data beyond the bounds of the array. Anything can happen - it might work or you might get a seg fault.

Comment: u r right, what i did was i put EOF myself at the end of last line and my code worked just fine thank u

Answer (score 1):

Your `b` is 5, still you have several extra blank lines in your input file.

If you increase `c` size by doing `char c[b*2][128];` ,it won't crash.

Else remove extra newlines from your input file.

Comment: actually i copy pasted the data in the file while writing the question actually there are no extra newlines in my file

Comment: @mohit there must be a newline at last, you can check `i` value by commenting the `c` operation.

Comment: shouldn't getline stop input if it encounters EOF